# Measured Value of Hubble's Constant

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, space-expansion, astronomy

As we know, Hubble's Constant is not exactly a constant, but its value varies with time. However, we also speak of measuring its present-day value. The measurements by cosmic distance ladder would require us to observe the light from a supernova, which would take quite some time to reach us. So, is the value of Hubble's Constant calculated from this the present-day value, or the value from the past, when the supernova occurred? Also, would there be a significant difference between both the values?

Comment: In researching this, I discovered there is an astronomy stack exchange where you might get a better answer. For instance look at the response to this post: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/why-dimmer-high-redshift-supernovae-means-the-expansion-is-accelerating-if-the?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @JohnA. astronomy & astrophysics questions are still on topic here (and there is a non-negligible overlap of users on both sites)

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to point OP to a useful resource. I don’t think astro is not physics. I’d answer the question if I was confident.

Comment: Better answers are here though https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/25982/does-the-hubble-constant-depend-on-redshift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People don't calculate the "value of the Hubble's Constant". They calculate $H_0$ ([see example from Planck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_(spacecraft)#2018_final_data_release)). $H_0$ is the value of the Hubble parameter at the present time (that's what the $0$ means). The value of the Hubble parameter can indeed change significantly between when the supernova occurred and now.

Comment: So this $H_{0}$ calculated is not the value from when the supernova occurred, right?

Comment: @VGovind Yes. <length>